# Android Studio not saving Device for Preview layout on exit

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, intellij-idea, virtual-device-manager

Hey all I've been looking far and wide trying to figure out how to save my preview setting's in Android Studio version:

> Electric Eel 2022.1.1 Canary 3
> Build #AI-213.7172.25.2211.8624637, built on May 20, 2022

Every time I change the **Device For Preview** to what I am always using (**Lenovo Tablet API 29 in the example here**):

[image]

And also change the **orientation** to **Landscape**:

[image]

Which should **always stay looking like this** for not just this layout but all others I have as well:

[image]

Then **close Android Studio and open it again** its **right back to what it seems to always default to** even though I changed it....

Here is a demo of me **opening the Android Studies** once to **set the settings I am wanting it to save**, **saving it** then **exiting**. I then **start Android Studio again** to show that it **does not have my saved Device for Preview nor the orientation**.

[image]

My device is setup correctly to mirror what I have chosen in the Device for Preview:

[image]

So, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think that is just a preview option and it doesn't save your app's orientation. But try this code and I hope it will help you.

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

You need to add this code in each relevant java activity of its layout.